# PropType optional to react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, react-redux, react-props

I have the below common component

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Input from '../component/Input'; //internal component 

const CustomInput = props => {
  const { label, updateInputField } = props;
  return (
    <Input
      label={label}
      changeField={updateInputField}
  )
}

CustomInput.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string,
  updateInputField: PropTypes.func
}

export default CustomInput;
```

Now i am using these component at several places like below

```
<CustomInput 
  label="401Balance"
  updateInputField={inputFieldHandler}
/>
```

so this one works.. but there are some places where I am not using the updateInputField as a prop. for e.g.

```
<CustomInput 
  label="savingsBalance"
/>
```

How do i not pass the prop and ensure it doesnot fail. Can someone please suggest.

Comment: set default props?

Comment: It's unclear why you would do this? Is it a disabled/readonly field or something?

Comment: @Adam- the above solution shared by kind user didnt work. can you share your answer as its a little confusing from comment

Comment: @Adam- There are some component which doesnot need to have a inputHandler function. Its just for display. whereas at some places i need to handle onChange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either set a default value to secure the case if no function was passed:

```
const { label, updateInputField = () => {} } = props;
```

or (probably a better approach) - create a separate function and add a simple condition:

```
const CustomInput = props => {
  const { label, updateInputField } = props;

  const fn = () => {
     if (updateInputField) {
        updateInputField();
     }
  };

  return (
     <Input
        label={label}
        changeField={fn}
     />
  );
}
```

Comment: @RaviK I gave you two, tested and correct solutions. If none of them works for you, probably the issue is somewhere else.